# How to pass input parameters to azure python3 runbook from adf webhook activity

Tags: python, azure-data-factory, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I want to pass parameters from azure data factory pipeline webhook activity to my azure automation python runbook.
How do I do that?

Comment: Do you mind use web activity instead of webhook in data factory ?

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, I test it in my side and found it is difficult to request the python runbook by webhook activity in data factory pipeline. My python code in runbook show like below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import re
import json
from urllib import parse

def fixJSON(string):
  res = re.sub(r"([^{}:,]+):([^{}:,]+),?", r'"\1":"\2",', string )
  res = re.sub('"[ ]*,[ ]*}', '"}', res)
  # and empty string
  res = re.sub("\"(''|\")\"", '""', res)
  # property : {...}
  res = re.sub(r"([^{}:,]+)(?=:{)", r'"\1"', res )
  return res

print("===")

test = str(sys.argv[1])
jsonStr = fixJSON(test)

jsonStr = jsonStr.replace("\"\"", "\"")
print(jsonStr)

jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)
print(jsonData["RequestBody"])
```

I test it with request body:

```
{
    "name":"hury"
}
```

If I test it in postman like below screenshot(no newline character in request body), it works fine:

[image]

But if there are newline character in request body(like below screenshot), it always fail when execute the `\r\n` in python runbook. And unfortunately, it seems we can't remove the newline character in python runbook(I test with many ways such as `replace("\r\n", "")`, `xxx.rstrip()`, all of them don't work)
[image]

If we just need to request in postman, we can set the request body without newline character. But if we request it in webhook activity in data factory, it seems the request body will be formatted with newline character even though I just set the request body in one line:
[image]

So I suggest you to use "Web" activity instead of "Webhook" activity, because in "Web" activity we can input a string instead of a json data as request body. If in "Webhook" activity, it doesn't allow us to input an invalid json data in request body.

[image]

Comment: Continuing on the same i have another question. Since azure python runbook supports positional parameter , Is it really possible to pass the parameter values  from ADF web activity to sys.argv variables which has been defined in python runbook?

Comment: @Parul Sorry, I'm not sure. What do you mean of positional parameter ? As far as I know, we can define parameter in powershell runbook, but I don't know how to define parameters in python runbook.

Comment: Unlike powershell i dont see any option through which  we can pass the input params in python runbook. The only way is by "importing sys" and by using sys.argv variable to get the parameter values which can be passed in test pane while starting the runbook. I referred below link(Use Input parameter)  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/learn/automation-tutorial-runbook-textual-python2  .  Moreover my requirement is to pass input value to python runbook using adf .